# Register Global Commands Discord

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to get my commands to register globally.. When adding to the guild server the commands added immediately, but when adding the bot to my other 2 discord servers they show no available commands even after the hour and using the application.command scope. Looking for any advice. Thank you

Here is my code

```
# region Application event
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    """Called when the client is done preparing the data received from Discord."""
    await client.wait_until_ready()

    Logger.info(f'Connected to {database.driver.value} database')
    Logger.info(f'Logged on as {client.user}')
    Logger.info(f'Add to Server: {invite_link}')

    if not public and not whitelist_guilds:
        Logger.warning('Environment variable WHITELIST_GUILDS is empty! Please set the environment variable.')

    await sync_commands(whitelist_guilds)
    await tasks_fetch_messages()

    if not tasks_query.is_running():
        tasks_query.start()


@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild: discord.Guild):
    """Called when a Guild is either created by the Client or when the Client joins a guild."""
    Logger.info(f'{client.user} joined {guild.name}({guild.id}) ðŸŽ‰.')

    if public:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            webhook = Webhook.from_url(os.getenv('APP_PUBLIC_WEBHOOK_URL'), session=session)
            await webhook.send(f'<@{client.user.id}> joined {guild.name}({guild.id}) ðŸŽ‰.')
            return

    # Sync the commands to guild when AARP joins a guild.
    if guild.id in [guild.id for guild in whitelist_guilds]:
        await sync_commands([discord.Object(id=guild.id)])


@client.event
async def on_guild_remove(guild: discord.Guild):
    """Remove all associated servers in database when AARP leaves"""
    await database.delete_servers(guild_id=guild.id)
    Logger.info(f'{client.user} left {guild.name}({guild.id}), associated servers were deleted.')


@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel: discord.abc.GuildChannel):
    """Remove all associated servers in database when channel deletes"""
    await database.delete_servers(channel_id=channel.id)
    Logger.info(f'Channel #{channel.name}({channel.id}) deleted, associated servers were deleted.')


async def sync_commands(guilds: list[discord.Object]):
    """Syncs the application commands to Discord."""
    if not public:
        for guild in guilds:
            await tree_sync(guild)

        # Remove global commands
        tree.clear_commands(guild=None)

    await tree_sync()


async def tree_sync(guild: discord.Object = None):
    """Syncs the application commands to Discord."""
    try:
        await tree.set_translator(Translator())
        await tree.sync(guild=guild)

        if public:
            Logger.info('Sync the commands to Discord. Global commands take up to 1-hour to propagate.')
        elif guild is not None:
            Logger.info(f'Sync the commands to guild {guild.id}. Guild commands propagate instantly.')
    except discord.ClientException as e:
        Logger.error(f'The client does not have an application ID. {e} {guild.id if guild else ""}')
    except discord.Forbidden as e:
        Logger.error(f'The client does not have the applications.commands scope in the guild. {e} {guild.id if guild else ""}')
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        Logger.error(f'Syncing the commands failed. {e} {guild.id if guild else ""}')
# endregion
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).